# App crashes on connection change using deepstream

Tags: android, runtime-error, deepstream.io

While i'm changing connection, my app crashes and shows the following stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-3
    Process: com.app.teemchat, PID: 9383
    io.deepstream.DeepstreamException: CONNECTION_ERROR: null
        at io.deepstream.DeepstreamClientAbstract.onError(DeepstreamClientAbstract.java:59)
        at io.deepstream.Connection$1.run(Connection.java:187)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Please help me to solve this problem...

```
client.addConnectionChangeListener(new ConnectionStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void connectionStateChanged(ConnectionState connectionState) throws RuntimeException {
        Log.w(Tag, "ConnectionChange>>> " + connectionState.toString());
        if (connectionState.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ConnectionState.ERROR.toString())) {
           client.close();
           doLogin();
           }

           if (connectionState.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ConnectionState.CLOSED.toString())) {
              doLogin();
              }
        }
});
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/deepstreamIO/deepstream.io/issues/591#issuecomment-339328749

Comment: no its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlexBHarley says that you need to add `setRuntimeErrorHandler`
https://github.com/deepstreamIO/deepstream.io-client-java/issues/85

> this is expected in the sense that the connection has died, so there
>   is a CONNECTION_ERROR. If you don't want this to throw an exception
>   you can put a listener on the error event with
>   client.setRuntimeErrorHandler. Admittedly the reason could be better
>   than null. The current approach is either one of two things,
>
> infinite reconnect attempts store some local state and restart the
>   session when internet connectivity comes back. We're hoping to tackle
>   some better offline first functionality with resuming sessions and the
>   like, in the near future.